# Bootstrap 3 grid - images overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to build a site using bootstrap 3. I want to use the grid layout for a section with three points but whenever I add it, the images overlap and are not centered when the browser is below the SM breakpoint.

Here is the HTML.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head lang="en">
            <!--Meta Data-->
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="keywords" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="Luke Bouch">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Always Ready Power</title>

            <!--Styles-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!--BootStrap CDN-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
            
        </head>

        <body>

            <nav class="topNav">
                <div class="container">
                    <img class="navLogo centerMobile" src="assets/20200811-ARLogo-White.png" alt="two kids looking out the window">
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="hero col-xs-12">
                        <h1>Keep your family safe<br/><span class="newLine">with a whole house generator</span></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="horizonralLayout row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <img src="assets/point1.png">
                            <h2>It's only a matter of time<span class="newLine">before your stuck without power</span></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <img src="assets/point2.png">
                            <h2>It's only a matter of time<span class="newLine">before your stuck without power</span></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <img src="assets/point3.png">
                            <h2>It's only a matter of time<span class="newLine">before your stuck without power</span></h2>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Scripts-->
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

And here is the CSS.

```
/* --- IMPORT --- */
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/ptx4dws.css");

/* --- MOBILE ---*/


/* Global */
h1 {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

h2 {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.newLine {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.break {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
.centerMobile {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* NavBar */
.topNav {
  background-color: rgb(232, 19, 35);
}
.navLogo {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  align-content: center;
}

.menuList {
  list-style: none;
  
}

.topNav li {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.topNav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  
}

.topNav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Hero */
.hero {
  padding: 25vw 5vw 25vw 5vw;
  background-image: url(/assets/heroBG.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.hero .newLine {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* Horizontal Layout*/
.horizontalLayout .item {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I may have just figured it out. I need the responsive-image class added, right?

But I still have the problem of the columns not being centered when the mobile breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues - first - you are not applying any styling for the xs- class -so it will be taking up the entire width (if you do not apply a column designation - the element will be at 100% of the width - as if you had col-xs-12.

If you still want the 3 images across - then you will need to apply a col-xs-4 to the divs with col-sm-4. Alternatively - you might want them to be different porpotional widths on the xs size - so you might want col-xs-6 col-sm-4" and have the images on two lines.

And second - you have a discrepancy in the code between the html class and the associatd styling - horizontalLayout needs to be updated in the html

```
//html

 <div class="horizonralLayout row">

/css 

/* Horizontal Layout*/
.horizontalLayout .item {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

And a suggestion - investigate the  element for your images - its the right tool for displaying the content you are showing here.

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
   <figure>
     <img src="assets/point3.png">
     <figcaption>
        It's only a matter of time<span class="newLine">before your stuck without power</span>
     </figcaption>
   </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: I added the responsive image class to all the images, added the images within a figure tag as you suggested, and fixed the spelling error. However, I still have the problem of the images not fill the entire content width (or at least be centered) when at the tablet or mobile sizes.

I have a live demo with images and everything at https://lukebouch.com/arp